# Style object is not applied in Component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 25,
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 20,
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
    },
});

const Button = ({
    children = 'NO CONTENT HERE',
    color = 'red',
    onPress,
    style = {},
}) => {

    return <View
        style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[{ backgroundColor: color }, styles.button, style]}
            onPress={onPress}>
            {children}
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
}

Button.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string,
    onPress: PropTypes.func,
    style: PropTypes.object
}

export default Button;
```

I use the Component `<Button />` and do not pass a `color prop` to it. I expect the `<Button />` to become red. However, it is white. When I pass a `color prop`, lets say green, it does not work neither. However, when I add a `backgroundColor` to the `StyleSheet.button` it gets applied. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order in which you apply the styles.

Try changing it to

```
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.button, style, { backgroundColor: color }]}
            onPress={onPress}>
```

When you pass in multiple values with the same key, the last value is the one that gets used.

Answer (score -1):

In React-Native, color props for Button works based on the mobile platform whether it’s an iOS or Android. When we pass color prop to a button, it changes the text color in iOS and a background-color in Android. So, it’s better to not rely on this prop for your requirement.

You may check the official React-Native documentation for button here-

https://reactnative.dev/docs/button

I would suggest to use a separate class to apply color to the button.

Comment: The `<Button />` Component is a class I wrote. `<View />` and `<TouchableOpacity />` are the ones coming from `RN`. And they take `backgroundColor`.